# Python&Django: What does ** mean

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Possibly i know the following uses of **

Power

```
x ** y # x power y equivalent to pow(x,y)
```

Passing indefinite number of args

```
def sample(x, **other):
    print(x, other.keys)
sample(x=2,y=3,z=4)
```

But i don't understand when its used as follow( in [Serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances))

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    return Comment(**validated_data)
```

Can someone give me a hint of what is happening there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the opposite of your second example. When in the definition of a function, the `**` operator gathers all the named arguments and makes a dictionary. When calling a function, it takes a dictionary and breaks it into named arguments

So, if you have

```
values = {'x': 1, 'y': 2}
f(**values)
```

it is the equivalent of

```
f(x=1, y=2)
```